# Centos system. It cannot generate pictures according to apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

My system is centos6,I have written a php script and a python script and the php script will invoke the python script.And the python script will invoke two software:blast and RNAfold,it will generate some word results and picture results. It's ok when this command running on shell.But only word results generate ，it cannot generate pictures.I used to search this question and someone said the apache forbid generate pictures according softwares because of security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look in your logs and see if there are any relevant messages.

Don't forget the audit.log as SELinux may be playing a part here.

You should also look at what's returned by the functions() you're using to call the external programs the information provided will likely lead to a solution.